# apache isis simple-app clean install fails

Tags: maven-3, isis

I am trying apache isis for the first time on my Windows machine (following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTNHR5EdAs8&list=PLbRpnAmQ6xsBGB_mRAUob8WRBsSL_IsBO), I executed the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.isis.archetype" "-D archetypeArtifactId=simpleapp-archetype" "-D archetypeVersion=1.16.2""-D groupId=com.mycompany""-D artifactId=myapp""-D version=1.0-SNAPSHOT" "-B"
```

Which created the myapp in a folder.

After that I Cd'd in myapp folder and executed `mvn clean install` which eventually failed with following error message:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] SimpleApp Parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT ...................... SUCCESS [  4.576 s]
[INFO] SimpleApp Simple Module ............................ FAILURE [ 22.055 s]
[INFO] SimpleApp Application .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] SimpleApp Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.747 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-21T08:19:19+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:4.0.5:enhance (process-classes) on project myapp-module-simple: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer: InvocationTargetException: java/sql/Date: java.sql.Date -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :myapp-module-simple
PS E:\Apache isis\test_project\myapp>
```

Did I miss anything? Any dependencies?

Comment: which version of Java?  Currently Apache Isis only supports up to Java 8, so possibly this is your issue?

Comment: It did work! It was Java version issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer below, could you mark it as accepted?  Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this writing Apache Isis only runs on Java 7 and 8.  We are aiming to be compatible with Java 11 when it ships in Sept/Oct (as that is the next LTS version of Java).